# Отправка запросов через httpie

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, httpie

Помогите разобраться. Пытаюсь работать через httpie. У меня проект сайт с постами и комментариями к ним. Пост может создать только авторизованный пользователь. Получить токен я смог так:

```
$ http POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/api-token-auth/ username='admin' password='admin'
```

Но что дальше делать не знаю. Никак не пойму как этот токен передать в запрос, чтоб создать пост.  А иначе пишет:

```
{
    "detail": "Учетные данные не были предоставлены."
}
```

Подскажите как сделать, чтоб токен передавался в запросах?

Так у меня в настройках:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {        
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated', 
    ],

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ]
}
```

Если нужна ещё какая-то информация, скажите я пришлю.

Comment: REST_FRAMEWORK = {        
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated', 
    ],

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ]
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TokenAuthentication](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication) принмает токен в header-е:

```
Authorization: Token 9944b09199c62bcf9418ad846dd0e4bbdfc6ee4b
```

Используя httpie это можно сделать так:

```
http GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/some/endpoint 'Authorization: Token 9944b09199c62bcf9418ad846dd0e4bbdfc6ee4b'
```

Comment: А пост то как создать?

Comment: Мне не известно, как в вашем приложении называются ендпоинты и какие параметры они принимают (это никому кроме авторов и людей имеющих доступ к коду либо документации неизвестно). Я понял проблему так, что вы не знаете как передать токен.

Comment: Получилось!!! Спасибо!))